# Generate difference between observations as new variable in Stata

Tags: stata

I am trying to get the difference between the natural logarithms of two consecutive observations for a set of variables.

My approach is as follows

```
. gen abandon_qry_ln = ln(abandon_qry) - ln(abandon_qry) [_n-1]
```

But I get the error `weights not allowed`.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Stuff like "Thanks" or your signature should be left out of questions. If you want to give personal information, edit your profile, e.g. to use your real name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could work with

```
gen difference = ln(abandon_qry) - ln(abandon_qry[_n-1])
```

or

```
gen ln_abandon_qry = ln(abandon_qry) 
gen difference = ln_abandon_qry - ln_abandon_qry[_n-1]
```

You were trying to subscript an expression. You may subscript a variable or a matrix in Stata, but not in general an expression.